# How to move a react.js app on spark-java?

Tags: spark-java

I have a web app with a backend using SparkJava backend, and a React app served using node deployed separately. I am hoping to find a way to run the react app on top of sparkjava (bounded together in a uber jar) instead of serving from node.js. I tried to move the react app (the build folder generated by `npm run build`) inside `src/main/resources/public` and point to that folder with `staticFiles.location("/public");` in SparkJava, but that did not work. Is there a way to accomplish this without rewriting the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach (serving the compiled resources through some route on the SparkJava server) is logically sound, you just need to ensure that the react app is served on all "routes" that are not covered by an api.

More details about what is going wrong would be helpful though.